# Azure B2C Custom policy - Changing the default action on email verification page

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Using a B2C custom policy when you press enter on the email verification page in the screenshot below. The default is to click the continue button, this doesnt make a lot of sense on the first step of typing your email and wanting to press the send code button.

[image]

How can I change this behavior so that the send verification code button is pressed instead of the continue button?

I tried adding some javascript with an eventlisetner to the text box but this just ends up clicking both the continue button AND the send verification code.

```
var input = document.getElementById("email");

    input.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
      // If the user presses the "Enter" key on the keyboard
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        // Cancel the default action, if needed
        event.preventDefault();
        // Trigger the button element with a click
        document.getElementById("email_ver_but_send").click();
      }
    });
```